# Upload file as column field in doc library

Tags: document-library

I have a document library and my users want to be able to upload/associate another document to an already uploaded one in the library. I was thinking another column but there isn't a field for a file upload.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### **Option 1**

You can use column type "`Multiple line of Text`" with option "`Enhanced Rich Text`". In this column type you get the functionality to upload file.

[image]

This works in SharePoint 2010 and 2013. I am not sure about SharePoint 2007.

### **Option 2**

Other option will be to add [Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7?CorrelationId=ec53261a-025e-443a-8efb-396d463c18aa&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc277149834) site column and add it to your list. This field allow to browse and upload a file to document library.

For this you will need to activate Publishing feature of a site. And then go to site columns and create a new column of type `Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing` Then add this newly created site column in your document library.

For more help refer this link:

https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/using-full-html-content-with-formatting-and-constraints-for-publishing-columns-in-document-libraries-and-lists/

Comment: Anything that would be a tad more intuitive for my users?

Comment: Check my updated answer with another option

Comment: So for Option 1 I added the enhanced rich text field and I don't get any upload button.  just a text box when I go to edit properties.   Also I did option 2 and it does let me browse but only shows me my site documents and pages.  not a browse box on my computer.

Comment: Yes Option 2 is restricted for SharePoint site only.  For option 1 make sure that you have selected "Enhanced Rich Text" option not "Plain text" while creating column. And inside new/edit form click on text box and then in ribbon click on insert. This will give option to upload file.

Comment: hmm so for option #1 I have added it but I don't have an insert menu.  all I have is an Edit menu with no upload.